# objects turned white

Tags: rendering

I don't know what causes this but everything looks white in material preview and in render

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe your light is too strong?

Comment: I've check my light and its not that strong, I also tried deleting my lights and still doesn't fix my problem

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or pasteall if it's heavy: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I don't wanna redo all my work, It take me 6 hrs creating leaves and grass also the shading took me an hour as a beginner

Comment: okay, wait. tnx a lot

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3Xq9LkEN

Comment: I can't make Eevee work properly on my computer, but it works fine with Cycles, does it on your computer?

Comment: i've tried in cycle but rendering makes it crash

Comment: ow it works in cycle ! thank you !!!

Comment: well it doesn't answer your question though  ;)

Comment: I was in cycle when I'm shading, maybe I did something wrong lmao

Comment: thanks anyway ! I'll probably gonna reduce the grass so it would render in cycle. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I was completely black on my computer.But selecting one of the objects and going into local view and then out seems to fix the issue.I think it's a bug.